# Reading a text file and getting information by line C#

Tags: c#

When reading a text file by using StreamReader, how can I get information from the contents on that line

for example:

```
Line 1: Hi there, my name is bob
Line 2: 1234563 90312
Line 3: I jumped over the moon
```

How would I detect 90312 on line 2? or anything else I may want on other lines?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by detect 903012?

Comment: So what defines 90312?

Comment: afaiu, he wants to tokenize the input line by line.

Comment: If you could explain more; What info do you want to get from the file?
How are this information is sorted in your file? is it a heterogeneous data? or there is a structured way used while creating the file?

Comment: I just want to detect certain characters in the file such as strings and int line by line.

Comment: Many ways to do this, And I see a lot have already posted good answers, you can simply use a regular expression to check if the line contains only numbers or starts with numbers, or any kind of validation you want, and do you action based on that

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the current line contains some specific string. Such as:

```
string line;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();

    if(line.Contains("90312"))
    {
      // Do something fancy here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you probably want to read a line into a variable and then tokenize it based on word-to-word basis.

You can use > `stringObject.Split(' ');` where, `stringObject` contains the line in question.